# Animating during momentum scroll in react-native?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

I'm attempting to create a custom NavBar on a screen that renders a ScrollView. Inside the NavBar, there's a button, that when pressed, causes the NavBar to translate downwards, thereby giving the appearance that the NavBar is expanding (This is done using `Animated.spring()` with the `useNativeDriver` option). Everything is working great, except if the ScrollView is still scrolling at the time the button is tapped (ie: when "momentum" scroll is taking place). In this scenario, the onPress handler that kicks off the NavBar animation is invoked as expected, but calls to `Animated.spring()` do not cause any animation to take place. Is it possible to either have the NavBar "expansion" animation to occur during the scroll, or pause the scroll to allow animation to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Like it's explained in RN [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#working-with-animations) the animation type you using are stoped by gesture events like scrolling, better use `Animated.event()` with `onScroll`props combined with an interpolation animation to animate you footer.